# Filter data from two tables based on one condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables.

this is buy table :

```
+--------+-----------------+---------------+
| id_buy | date            | market        |
+--------+-----------------+---------------+
|  6     | 2017-07-30      | Amazon        |
|  7     | 2017-08-02      | Amazon        |
| 17     | 2017-08-16      | Ebay          |
| 18     | 2017-08-09      | Banggood      |
| 19     | 2017-09-14      | Ebay          |
+--------+-----------------+---------------+
```

and this is item table :

```
+---------+----------------+-------------------------+
| id_item | id_buy         | items                   |
+---------+----------------+-------------------------+
|  6      |              6 | Filter Oli OH           |
|  7      |              6 | Filter Solar Halus OH   |
|  8      |              6 | Switch Klakson 12/24 V  |
|  9      |              6 | Kampas Rem 188 + Paku F |
| 10      |              7 | Kain Rem 188            |
| 11      |              7 | Kain Rem 200            |
| 23      |             17 | Kompresor Mesin         |
| 24      |             18 | Silikon                 |
| 25      |             19 | Kompresor Mesin Ganda   |
+---------+----------------+-------------------------+
```

I want to filter the buy and item table based on market field, so it can display the result like this :

if I filter with market='Amazon' :

```
+--------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------------+
| id_buy | date            | market        | items                   |
+--------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------------+
|  6     | 2017-07-30      | Amazon        | Filter Oli OH           |
|  6     | 2017-07-30      | Amazon        | Filter Solar Halus OH   |
|  6     | 2017-07-30      | Amazon        | Switch Klakson 12/24 V  |
|  6     | 2017-07-30      | Amazon        | Kampas Rem 188 + Paku F |
|  7     | 2017-08-02      | Amazon        | Kain Rem 188            |
|  7     | 2017-08-02      | Amazon        | Kain Rem 200            |
+--------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------------+
```

if I filter with market='Ebay' :

```
+--------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------------+
| id_buy | date            | market        | items                   |
+--------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------------+
| 17     | 2017-08-16      | Ebay          | Kompresor Mesin         |
| 19     | 2017-09-14      | Ebay          | Kompresor Mesin Ganda   |
+--------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------------+
```

if I filter with market='Banggood' :

```
+--------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------------+
| id_buy | date            | market        | items                   |
+--------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------------+
| 18     | 2017-08-09      | Banggood      | Silikon                 |
+--------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------------+
```

This is my example query to show the result, but not really work :

```
select buy.id_buy, buy.date, buy.market, item.items from buy, item where buy.id_buy in(17,19) and item.id_buy in(17,19);
```

and this is the query result :

```
+--------+-----------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| id_buy | date            | market    | items                 |
+--------+-----------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| 17     | 2017-08-16      | Ebay      | Kompresor Mesin       |
| 19     | 2017-09-14      | Ebay      | Kompresor Mesin       |
| 17     | 2017-08-16      | Ebay      | Kompresor Mesin Ganda |
| 19     | 2017-09-14      | Ebay      | Kompresor Mesin Ganda |
+--------+-----------------+-----------+-----------------------+
```

I am confuse why the result is double..

Comment: You need to GROUP BY, and/or DISTINCT. This has been asked many times before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your join. Currently you're using a [cross join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join) with `buy, item`, which will get you the cartesian product of the two tables. (Meaning, since you haven't defined which columns in each table represent the relationship, you get a query result that has every row in item for each row in buy, which explains your double results.)

You need to specify the columns that define your join instead.

```
SELECT buy.id_buy, buy.date, buy.market, item.items
FROM buy INNER JOIN item on buy.id_buy = item.id_buy
```

Then you can put whatever you need to in the where clause.